# Search for simple product as a part of a grouped product

Tags: configurable-product, search

In our Magento 1.9.1.1 shop we have grouped products with simple products as it part.
The simple products have the setting - not visible individually
The grouped products have setting - visible in Catalog and search.
As the result, when our customers are trying to search for the simple product by its number or title - the search result say: the are no items you are looking for.

Is this possible, that when a customer is searching for the simple product that is a part of a grouped product, in search autocomplete and among search results he/she can see the grouped product, that is a parent item for the product he is looking for.

Is there any module that can help us to solve the issue?